# Checking if x>y without if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

In Python, is it possible to check whether x>y without using the if statement?

Comment: Sure you can. `x>y`. The question is, what do you want to do with that knowledge?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you would even want/need to do something like that? Context may help you get a better answer to the question.

Comment: What context would you want to do this?

Comment: I think I'm going to start closing this sort of question as too localised ("... or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable ...") since I can't see it being useful to _anyone_ that's not a raving loony. No offence intended, infoquad :-)

Comment: @infoquad is probably asking about how to do it without any control statements.

Comment: It's nothing practical. Just "stumbled" across this challenge...

Answer (score 13):

There are a variety of ways to go about this:

```
print "yes" if x > y else "no"
```

or:

```
print ["no", "yes"][x > y]
```

or:

```
print x > y and "yes" or "no"
```

(at least, this is what my mind-reading powers think that you're doing)

Comment: the first solution uses if :)

Comment: ... but not as a statement :p

Comment: all solutions uses implicit if, the interpreter traduce 3 codes to same hardware instructions WITH if

Comment: @Gustavo: The question was related to if statements in Python, not in machine code.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> x=1
>>> y=2
>>> "YNEOS"[x<y::2]
'NO'
>>> x=3
>>> "YNEOS"[x<y::2]
'YES'
```

Comment: @infoquad, x<y is True or False which is treated as the number 1 or 0. also see http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
x > y
```

This returns true if x is larger than y, and there is no if statement involved.

Comment: Not, in this code no check is performed, it only returns true or false but no test

Answer (score 2):

The question is really vague. You could check if x is greater than y in a while loop, or you could use the expression to return a boolean or whatever.

It would be a lot easier to answer if you gave us an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

This question is awful, but I suppose I'll contribute an answer anyway:

```
bool(x>y)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x*(x>y) + y*(x<y)
```

this will return the greater of x,y

Answer (score 1):

This Answer comes late.
If u just want to return anything u can do it with a while loop. Following Example:

```
while x > y:
    # Do anything.
    break
```

Or if u dont want to return u can use break in the Loop After u did what every u want to do.
Sorry for my Bad English, i still hope this Answer helped anyway.

Comment: This is an answer to the fizzbuzz question, not to the original question.

Comment: We call it "example" :). It work's in every case, not only fizzbuzz.

Comment: Your "example" of using a while loop to evaluate a condition for true or false value doesn't include the original question of evaluating if x>y. That is why I commented on it. Try changing your example fit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
x > y
```

or

```
bool(x>y)
```

in the second case bool are unecessary, in two codes true or false are returned, however, no checks by the return are performed, and this is your question. NOT, a if statement have a identical translation in hardware and to perform an test (if) in hardware you realy need to use if or an most high level statment